# Erro onclick Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Ao tentar realizar o evento de click, retorna a seguinte mensagem no console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
>       at calcularQuadrado (quadrado.js:3)
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:10)

```
<html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Exercicios</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="quadrado.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        Números <input type="text" name="txtNumeros">
        <input type="button" value="Calcular quadrado!" onclick="calcularQuadrado()">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Arquivo **quadrado.js**

```
    function calcularQuadrado() {
    var numeros = document.getElementById("txtNumeros").value;
    numeros = numeros.split("-");
    for (i=0; i=numeros.length; i++){
        quadrado = parseInt(numeros[i])*parseInt(numeros[i]);
        document.write("O quadrado de "+numeros[i]+ " é "+quadrado+"<br>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Erro no HTML

É um erro sintático, pois o atributo `onclick` não é valido para a tag `input`.

> Mais sobre as propriedades da tag `input` aqui:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

O correto é utilizar o `onclick` como propriedade de uma tag `<button>`, seu problema será resolvido deste jeito.

> Informação sobre `onclick` no `button` (em inglês):
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

### Erro no Javascript

Há um erro no seu Javascript, como foi citado pelo *Bruno Romualdo*.
Você está utilizando a propriedade `name` no seu `input`, e fazendo a referência `getElementByID` no seu Javascript. Como o próprio nome diz, esta chamada faz a relação pelo `ID`, nao pelo `name`. Para resolver, é necessário adicionar a propriedade `ID` ao seu `input`.

> Mais sobre o `getElementByID`
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Preciso, rápido e funcional! Obrigado de verdade!

Answer (score 2):

Você está usando:

`document.getElementById("txtNumeros").value; // pegar o elemento por id`

para pegar o valor do input, mas seu input não está com o id `txtNumeros` e sim com o atributo `name`:

`<input type="text" name="txtNumeros">`

altere ele para

`<input type="text" name="txtNumeros" id="txtNumeros"> // adicionando o atributo id no final`

que já vai funcionar.